# How to update variables that are inside a helper body in an Ember template

Tags: ember.js, properties, handlebars.js, computed-properties, computed-observable

Imagine a property `myNumber` in a controller that has a different random number every second. With this template you will see this change every second:

```
<h4>Random number</h4>
<p>{{myNumber}}</p>
```

However, when the number is only referenced inside a helper (e.g. `#if` or `#each`), **the number is not updated anymore.** This will only show the initial value:

```
<h4>Random number</h4>
{{#if model}}
    <p>{{myNumber}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

(Note that `myNumber` has no relation to `model`. Just using some random truthy property.)

Interestingly, when you add the reference to the property back to the root of the document, **the previously static numbers will now also update:**

```
<h4>Random number</h4>
{{myNumber}} -- Without this reference, references below won't update.
{{#if model}}
    <p>{{myNumber}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

### How can I have `myNumber` inside the helpers update, without showing the number in the root of my template?

I've tried adding the reference in html comments, but that doesn't work. I assume Ember doesn't draw elements that are not in the DOM:

```
<h4>Random number</h4>
<!-- {{myNumber}} -->
{{#if model}}
    <p>{{myNumber}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

What does work is adding the value to the DOM, but hiding it. However, this is an ugly solution:

```
<h4>Random number</h4>
<span style="display:none">
    {{myNumber}}
</span>
{{#if model}}
    <p>{{myNumber}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: I think we may need more information about the specific scenario that you're running into -- because I replicated your scenario here: https://ember-twiddle.com/4fa821853d28b600b0a74af3de8e2af8?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

and `myNumber` correctly updates every second. :-\

Comment: how is `myNumber` changing in your app?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli this is strange! I have tried to recreate my app in twiddle with increasing complexity, but it doesn't show the behavior I am observing locally. I have something different in my environment anyway, because in twiddle I cannot use 'this' two levels deep (e.g. controller>actions>promise) but locally I can. So in Twiddle I have to set `const controller = this` one level higher. I tried to change the Ember version (I use 3.1.4) in Twiddle but there is no change. In my app `myNumber` is changed like so: `this.send()` -> `action` -> `promise` -> `this.set()`

Comment: why can't you use `this` two levels deep? I think I may need to know more information about your specific setup.

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I don't know why, but if I had to guess, the ember-twiddle environment is too different because it uses hacks in order to offer this service. You'll understand from the comments in the code for [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2905579ee77c6defeebe2096142b8b01?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

Comment: Did you update something? Where should I look?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I added the `probeNumbers` action in the controller. Note that this answers your question _"why can't you use this two levels deep?"_ but I still cannot reproduce the issue in twiddle. I think `twiddle` is too different from `ember-cli`.

Comment: I'm just not convinced it's a twiddle vs ember-cli problem. 
also, have you thought about using async/await? it would clean up your code, and allow consistent this usage.
also, why _aren't_ you using an arrow function in that controller?
also, are you able to convert to a native class? I think that would solve some of the awkwardness.
what ember version are you on?

Comment: You can _observe_ that `this` isn't working there. I am not using an arrow function because arrow functions do not have a context. Referencing `this` is not a problem for me, it's only a problem on Twiddle. Thank you for thinking with me. I think we should wait a bit and see if someone _recognizes_ the issue of nested variables not working unless the variable is referenced in the root of a template.

Comment: arrow functions just don't _change_ the context / they inherit the parent context. so if you use an arrow function, you don't need `const controller = this`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bQaQoE5

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I stand corrected. You are correct. About the arrow function.

Comment: If you can not reproduce in twiddle a minimal git repo with reproduction can also help us

Comment: I think this works fine in normal scenario. There will be small issues in setting up `myNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an arrow function will solve your problem.

[image: alt]

Comment: This does nothing to solve the problem. The problem cannot be reproduced in Twiddle. I'll make a repository when I have some time.